# Bishop-Gromov inequality strengthened for anisotropic metrics?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The Bishop-Gromov inequality provides an upper-bound on the rate of growth of volume of a ball of radius $r$ in spaces that have a lower-bound on the Ricci curvature, $Ric \geq (n-1)K$.

(I am interested in the case where $K$ is negative, and where the space is homogeneous (i.e. every point is the same, as in a left-invariant metric on a Lie group), and where the dimensionality is large.)

Heuristically, the B-G inequality says that the volume of a ball of radius $r$ in the space is always smaller than the volume of a ball of radius $r$ in the hyperbolic space you would get by making the Ricci curvature uniformly equal to $(n-1)K$.

**My question** is whether we can make a stronger statement (a smaller upper-bound on the volume of a ball) in the case when the Ricci curvature is strongly anisotropic. The example I have in mind is a high-dimensional space with only a few directions come close to the lower bound $(n-1)K$; for almost all of the directions the Ricci curvature is positive.

I would be equally happy if the bound were expressed in terms of the Ricci curvature or in terms of the sectional curvatures.